# Asset Pipeline Issue Upgrading Rails 3.0 app to Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I've followed the instructions for the Railscast on upgrading a Rails app to 3.1:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1?view=asciicast

The server doesn't recognize requests for any folders within `app/assets`.

Just to be sure, I've run `rake rails:update` and diff'd the files against what we have.  It looks like every old config flag has been removed and every new config flag has been set.

When I load the homepage, I see the following in the javascript console:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js"

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3000/assets/application.css"
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I'm completely stumped, short of creating a new app and moving things over.

Comment: If bg.png is not the one in app/assets/images, do you recognize which bg.png it is? Is it in public/assets?

Comment: I ran this in the project `gfind -name "bg.png"` and there's only one bg.png that shows up.

Comment: Do you even have a public/assets directory? or public/javascripts or public/images? if so, remove (or move) them out

Comment: I don't have a public/assets folder or any of the other folders you listed.  @manglewood, the bg.png must've been cached from another project.

Comment: How are you requesting your assets? If requesting from the browser, the following should work: http://localhost:3000/assets/bg.png if you have bg.png in app/assets/images

Comment: @manglewood that's how I'm requesting them and that's how they're stored.  The asset pipeline isn't working--see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the `active_reload` gem in our project.  Disabling it in the gemfile and running `bundle install` fixed the issue

Apparently [the first statement on the project page is that it's incompatible with Rails 3.2.x](https://github.com/paneq/active_reload/).